# Rally API Defect Object Returning Partial Data

Tags: c#, soap, rally

I am using the Rally 1.4 version and I am trying to use the Rally API to return a full defect object;

```
String myQuery = "(FormattedID = " + defectID + ")";
QueryResult myArtifactReturn = RallyService.RallyService.query(SelectedWorkspace, "Defect", myQuery, "", true, 0, 100);
long mycount = myArtifactReturn.TotalResultCount;
if (mycount > 0)
{
    SelectedDefect = (Defect)myArtifactReturn.Results[0];
    SelectedDefect = (Defect)RallyService.RallyService.read(SelectedDefect);
}
```

This request works as the defect is found and the object is returned however the problem I face is that some information is available and some is not. For example, I can get the name, description and close date however I cannot see the FixedInBuild, VerifiedInBuild properties as they are set to null.

When I call the method via the Rally Web Service on the URL they provide I can see all the objects clearly so it must be something to do with the way I am making the query.

The query details are;

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("RallyIntegrationInfo")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://rallydev.com/webservice/v1_40/service", ResponseNamespace="http://rallydev.com/webservice/v1_40/service", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("queryOriginalReturn")]
    public QueryResult query(Workspace workspace, string artifactType, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("query")] string query1, string order, bool fetch, long start, long pagesize) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("query", new object[] {
                    workspace,
                    artifactType,
                    query1,
                    order,
                    fetch,
                    start,
                    pagesize});
        return ((QueryResult)(results[0]));
    }
```

This also occurs with the UserStory object, in this we are not getting the test cases and scheduled state, instead these are coming down as null.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some recent changes to Rally's Webservices API that resulted in non-backwards compatible changes to Rally's SOAP interface. There is a Defect logged with Rally's Engineering team concerning this. I would recommend that you file a Case with [Rally Support](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/help.sp?pp=contact) (rallysupport@rallydev.com) concerning this issue. Your Case can be linked to the Defect and you will be notified at such time as a fix is released.

Some helpful information to supply Rally Support:

- Version of WSAPI you are utilizing
- Information above from your post
- Version of Visual Studio

Comment: thanky you very much for the information. I will check it out.